# How can i install hudson on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: installation, hudson, ubuntu-10.10

When i try t install, i get error:

```
aptitude install hudson
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hudson 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 279 not upgraded.
Need to get 38.8MB of archives. After unpacking 39.7GB will be used.
WARNING: untrusted versions of the following packages will be installed!

Untrusted packages could compromise your system's security.
You should only proceed with the installation if you are certain that
this is what you want to do.

  hudson 

Do you want to ignore this warning and proceed anyway?
To continue, enter "Yes"; to abort, enter "No": Yes
Get:1 http://hudson-ci.org/debian/ binary/ hudson 1.397 [38.8MB]
Fetched 1B in 0s (2B/s)           
E: Failed to fetch http://hudson-ci.org/debian/binary/hudson_1.397_all.deb: Size mismatch
```

Comment: the .397 release was really skipped and is the same as 1.398. You must have hit the repo just at the right time when it was inconsistent.

Comment: It's still trying to hit 1.397 and I can't seem to get any of the suggestions to work with a fresh install of ubuntu.  Keeps saying Unable to fetch some archives... just after complaining about a size mismatch.  Is there a way to specify version?

Comment: I did succeed after I followed the instructions on this page http://hudson-ci.org/debian/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt-get clean

apt-get update

apt-get install hudson
```

this should work.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably best posted to serverfault.com; but regardless; it appears the mirror you are using is busted and you most likely downloaded an error page (which is why the failure).  Try doing an update for your repository to get the latest mirror information.

```
apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

execute `aptitude update` first

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I followed the steps here: http://makeitfaster.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/install-the-hudson-build-server-on-ubuntu-10-10-server/

Which then also failed at the "sudo dpkg --install /tmp/hudson.deb" line.  Then I did this:

aptitude install openjdk-6-jre

At which point hudson finished installing and came on line.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem...

> Need to get 38.8MB of archives. After
> this operation, 39.7GB of additional
> disk space will be used. WARNING: The
> following packages cannot be
> authenticated!
>
> hudson Install these
> packages without verification [y/N]? y
>
> Get:1 http://hudson-ci.org/debian/
> binary/ hudson 1.397 [38.8MB] Fetched
> 38.8MB in 59s (655kB/s)
>
> Failed to fetch
> http://hudson-ci.org/debian/binary/hudson_1.397_all.deb
> Size mismatch E: Unable to fetch some
> archives, maybe run apt-get update or
> try with --fix-missing?

I have done

apt-get clean

apt-get update

apt-get install hudson

as root.

Still don't understand what the size mismatch is - I can't see any errors downloaded.

The main difference between me and the original poster is that I *am* downloading 38.8MB, but it still reports the wrong size.

Comment: This just happened on two of my machines... Still don't know why it is trying to load 1.397 and not 1.398